# Printing out text in textarea in a loop

Tags: java

i have a button in java that calls a function when clicked and that function works just fine but the for loop won't refresh the text area. Instead at the end of the function (after 10s) it only shows i = 10 in the text area. I just simply want the text area to refresh and show i at every second and replace the i. I do not want to show them all at once, just replace them;

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    try
    { 
        input.setText("i = " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000); // delay of 1.000 seconds 
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep` blocks EDT, **don't** use it. Use [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: What technology are you using? Is it Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Swing, you could attempt using `append` instead, since I know that works with adding to the textarea:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        input.append("i = " + i + "\n");
    }
});
```

As Maroun suggested, use `Timer` after this to pace your appending.

Comment: I have tried that previously but the thing is I do not want a new line. I want the number to be replace by the next number every second

Comment: Try using the `.setText()` within the `invokeLater` and see if that was the issue to start with then.